# Avoiding the Integration Constant

Tags: calculus, notation, indefinite-integrals

I sometimes find writing and keeping track of the constants of integration a somewhat messy job. Yes, sometimes it's necessary but in many situations that I come across in my level of mathematics, it is a waste of time and space.

An exagerated example:
$$f''(x) = g''(x)\\
 \stackrel{\int\text{ing}}{\implies} f'(x) + C_1 = g'(x) + C_2\\
\stackrel{\int\text{ing}}{\implies} f(x) + C_3 + C_1x + C_4= g(x) + C_5 + C_2x + C_6\\
\implies f(x) = g(x) + C_ax + C_b 
$$
where $C_a = C_2 - C_1$ and $C_b = C_6 + C_5 - C_4 - C_3$

<sup>This just seems like a ridiculous amount of tracking in certain cases and I often just combine as many constants in one shot without mercy in most problems I face and never explain the sources of the constants (because it doesn't really matter) 

$\times$ Some people I know avoid distinguishing the constants by just marking them all as $C$ and only distinguish between coefficients and constants as I've illustrated in the last step of my example.

$\times$ Some other students leave out the constants all together and write a " *+ C* " only in last step but they don't realize that they are often neglecting terms where the constants turn into coefficients.</sup>

$\Large\star$ It isn't a mystery as to why the constant tickles people's lazy bones. The lethargic attitude almost everyone shows toward it is because that " *+ C* " is just **annoying**. Sure, it may seem necessary but what about in simplifications?

$$
\begin{align}
\int f'(x)\ \mathrm dx &= f(x) + C \\
&= f_1(x) + C \\
&= f_2 (x) + C \\
&= f_3 (x) + C \\
&= \dots \\
&= f_n(x) + C\\
\end{align}$$

where $f_{k\in \mathbb N}(x)$ is a simplified form of $f(x)$

It's usage is monotonous and seems absolutely unnecessary during simplification.

My question is hence this:

> **How can one safely hide the constant of integration during simplification of equations and what are the restrictions in such hiding?**

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: I am seeking a notation which would validly allow for a neglection of the constant during simplification of differential equations. Imagine 100 steps of simplification. The +C would be annoying. Apologies if this point was not clear through my rant.

Comment: Can't you use one constant?

Comment: @DigitalBrain: `...I often just combine as many constants in one shot without mercy...` Yes, that's what I do. But that *one* constant bothers me during simplification.

Comment: When you integrate both sides of an equation, you need one new constant of integration.  Period.  You have written 4 in a single step.

Comment: @Mike: My peers keep bugging me for a 'real way' to exclude writing the annoying " $ + \, C$ " during simplification of differential equations. Is there no way to write $\int f'(x) \mathrm \, dx \equiv f(x)$ ?

Comment: To be clear: When you're talking about application to diff-eqs, do you mean in the context of finding the general solution, or to solving initial value problems specifically?

Comment: @Semiclassical: Ofcourse I'm talking in the context of finding general solutions. I'm trying to hide an unnecessary variable. If I were given an initial value, I would not have an *arbitrary* constant to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use modular arithmetic:

$$\int f'(x) \, \mathrm dx \equiv f(x) \mod \Bbb R$$

But be warned, it has limitations during manipulation of the equation.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that there is a standard way of doing it but of course, you can invent your on. In this case, an equivalence relation or rather a sequence of equivalence relations:

For functions $f, g$, let $f \equiv_d g$ if there exists a polynomial $p$ of degree at most $d$, such that $f = g +p$. In this case, you want $\deg 0 = -1$.

We have $f \equiv_{-1} g$ iff $f=g$ and integrating raises the degree $d$ by one.

Your example becomes
$$\int f'(x) \operatorname{d}x \equiv_0 f(x) = f_1(x) = \dots = f_n(x)$$
and in a second step
$$\int f'(x) \operatorname{d}x = f_n(x) + C.$$

**Edit:** In this answer, I defined the symbol $\equiv$ (if you don't like it, you can replace it by something else, say $\sim$). Another way to phrase the definition is the following: For functions $f, g$ and $d \in \{-1, 0, 1, 2, \dots \}$, let $f \equiv_d g$ if the difference $f - g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d$. For every $d$, $\equiv_d$ is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) – the proof is easy.

Slightly abusing notation (I will identify a function $f$ with its term $f(x)$ for brevity), we have for example

- $f(x) \equiv_{-1} g(x)$ if and only if $f = g$, because the only degree-$(-1)$ polynomial is the zero polynomial, thus $f - g = 0$, i.e. $f = g$.
- $\sin x \equiv_0 \sin x + 15$, because $15$ is a degree-$0$ polynomial
- $f(x) \equiv_d f(x) + c_d x^d + c_{d-1} x^{d-1} + \dots + c_0$, because $c_d x^d + c_{d-1} x^{d-1} + \dots + c_0$ is a degree-$d$ polynomial

Now, whenever $f''(x) = g''(x)$, we know that $f'(x) + C = g'(x) + D$ with constants $C, D \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $f'(x) - g'(x) = D - C$ which is constant, i.e. a degree-$0$ polynomial. Using the notation defined above, we can write $f \equiv_0 g$, eliminating the explicit constant.

This also works for higher degrees. Say we know $f'(x) \equiv_d g'(x)$. Then there exists a degree-$d$ polynomial $p$ or more explicitly real numbers $c_0, \dots, c_d$, such that $f'(x) - g'(x) = p(x) = c_d x^d + \dots + c_0$. Integration:
$$f(x) - g(x) = \frac{c_d}{d+1} x^{d+1} + \dots + c_0 x + C$$
which is a degree-$(d+1)$ polynomial. Thus $f \equiv_{d+1} g$.

The nice thing about an equivalence relation is that it behaves in many ways like equality. For example, you can use it in an equality chain like
$$f_0(x) = f_1(x) \equiv_d f_2(x) = f_3(x)$$
if you keep in mind that you can only deduce $f_0(x) \equiv_d f_3(x)$ from that and *not* $f_0(x) = f_3(0)$.

Also note that this notation is *not* standard. If you want to use it and others to understand it, you will have to give the definition.

Comment: I love this answer but I am not able to understand what $f \equiv_d g$ means exactly and I would also like to know where you have borrowed this notation from, if you have?

Comment: Defining an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) is the natural thing to do in situations like this. Probably somebody did this before but I don't have a source for this. I will also try do add some detail to the answer.

Comment: Congrats, you've won the bounty for your splendid style but I've found something more standard that serves my needs better (see my answer) :D

Answer (score 4):

For the easy situation of one integration, you can write

$$
∫f(x)dx ∋ F(x) = F_1(x) = … = F_n(x)\\
\text{hence} ∫f(x)dx = F_n(x) + C
$$

It's because you can say that primitive operator function really gives you the set of all primitive functions, all of which differs by a constant. Then, to be consistent, you can say that the second equality is a set equality and $C$ is a set of all constants.

Comment: exactly the type of answer i'm looking for :D Wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the number of your constants by half by using only one constant each time you integrate. For example, when solving
$$r'(x)=s'(x)$$
write the answer as
$$r(x)=s(x)+C_1$$
rather than (as you were doing)
$$r(x)+C_1=s(x)+C_2$$
Using only one constant when integrating both sides of an equation is perfectly rigorous and the proof is obvious.

**ADDED:**

1) Another possibility is to use constants like $c,d,e,\ldots$ (or $k,l,m,\ldots$ or $p,q,r,\ldots$ or $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\ldots$) rather than $C_1,C_2,C_3,\ldots$. This does not reduce the number of constants but it does reduce the tiresome subscripts and make it *look* like there are fewer constants.

2) When you wrote "I often just combine as many constants in one shot without mercy..." I thought you meant things like changing $\pm C_1e^{x+C_2}$ to $C_1e^x$, which is less rigorous. Using only one constant per integration is a no-brainer.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was doing: `...I often just combine as many constants in one shot without mercy...`. My true problem is the boring repetition of the constant during simplification of equations

Comment: @Nick, not everything is fun in life. If you want to be correct, then just show the minimum number of constants that are necessary.

Comment: @k170: Imagine 100 steps of simplification, the +C will drive you mad. That's my real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way around your problem:

$\int f'(x) \mathrm dx = f(x) + C$ for some $C$. So

$$\begin{align}
\int f'(x)\ \mathrm dx - C &= f(x) \\
&= f_1(x) \\
&= f_2 (x) \\
&= f_3 (x) \\
&= \dots \\
&= f_n(x) \\
\end{align}$$

Therefore $\int f'(x) \mathrm dx = f_n(x) + C$ for some $C$.

I don't think this is exactly what you were looking for, but then I suspect that what you are looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: lol, good solution. But a notation can be 'invented' as @Eike suggests. Don't you think? Also, imagine simplifying both sides of a differential equation simultaneously, there isn't an escape from the `+C`s. (PS: Should I tag this as a soft question?)

Answer (score 2):

In certain circumstances, [Landau notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) (aka Big-O notation) can be used for this. So, for example, your first example would look something like:
$$
f''(x) = g''(x)\\
\stackrel{\int\text{ing}}{\implies} f'(x) + O(1) = g'(x) + O(1)\\
\stackrel{\int\text{ing}}{\implies} f(x) + O(x) = g(x) + O(x)\\
\implies f(x) = g(x) + O(x)
$$

and your second example would look like (maybe not such a great improvement):

$$
\begin{align}
\int f'(x)\ \mathrm dx &= f(x) + O(1) \\
&= f_1(x) + O(1) \\
&= f_2 (x) + O(1) \\
&= f_3 (x) + O(1) \\
&= \dots \\
&= f_n(x) + O(1)\\
\end{align}
$$

The caveat would be that this should probably only be used when you don't care too much about what is elided by the Big O (e.g.: $x + \frac{1}{log(x)} = O(x)$). And, yes, there can be some slipperiness with the use of the equals sign with Big O notation in these contexts (see the [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Equals_sign) on this) and if you're not careful you might end up tripping yourself up. But, I think if your uses are mainly like your first example, I think some sparing and/or careful use of Big O's might help.

Comment: Although this may not have exactly been what I was looking for, it is impressively relevant and useful. Thank you for this answer :D

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem (nuisance rather) that I actually make extensive use of is very similar to @EikeShulte's answer.

For an ordinary differential equation, suppose you have the following:

$$\int f'(x)dx=f(x)+C$$

This can be written in 'Don Juan' notation as

$$\int f'(x) dx = {}^0f(x)$$

Which translates as "f(x) has a polynomial of degree 0 after it with unknown coefficients". If you were to integrate that 30 more times and obtain a function $g(x)$ with, as you may have guessed, a polynomial of degree $30$ after with unknown coefficients, you could write it very simply with 'Don Juan' notation as

$${}^{30}g(x)$$

And for what other purposes does anybody really use that pre-superscript? I don't know of any, so I think this notation solves the problem pretty nicely.

But what if you know what $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ actually are with the exception of the polynomial of unknown coefficients? No problem! Suppose $g(x)$, the same one mentioned above, has $\sin(3x) + 3x^2-e^x$ before the polynomial. Then it can be written in 'Don Juan' notation as

$${}^{30}(\sin(3x) + 3x^2-e^x)$$

Comment: Dear Don Giovanni, your notation is as profound as your history.

Comment: I really can't tell whether you're being sarcastic or not.

Comment: T'was not intended to be sarcasm whence it was written. Btw, my remark was on the basis of the interpretation of Don Juan as a story of salvation. Yes, it was profound and creative.

Comment: Ah, I see. Don Giovanni has a great history. However, I actually got 'Don Juan' from a different set literature - The Teachings of Don Juan. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Teachings_of_Don_Juan

Answer (score 1):

Because a sum of constants can be any combination of constants, then we can substitute $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty C_i = C_1$

Similarily, $x(\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty C_i) = C_2$.

We have then, $\int\int\int\int\int\int\int dx$ having 6 constants, but that is unavoidable. We can forcefully combine constants with the same factor, because a constant+constant2 is just a constant.

Comment: You and @Rory seem to be under the impression that I am not able to digest the fact that the sum of constants is constant. this is not true. I do not blame you for this misinterpretation because a large section of my post is just a rant irellevant to the point which all other answers have addressed. I added those extra lines written in small font for the purpose of dramatically projecting my irritation with the constant. My sincerest Apologies.